# Kazakhstan visa in Uzbekistan?

Tags: visas, uzbekistan, kazakhstan, embassies, consulates

I'll be passing through Uzbekistan shortly, and will need another Kazakhstan tourist visa before I head back there.  What locations can I get this at, and any idea how long it will take to achieve?

Comment: Another dead question update :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According [this information](http://www.advantour.com/kazakhstan/visa.htm),

> You can apply for the Kazakhstan visa outside of Kazakhstan where
>   [Kazakhstan Embassy or Consulate](http://www.advantour.com/kazakhstan/embassies-in-kazakhstan4.htm) exist

In [Uzbekistan](http://www.advantour.com/kazakhstan/embassy-cis.htm) it is situated in:

> 70015 Toshkent shahar
>   Chehov 23 Str.
>   e-mail: kazembassy@kaz.uz
>   Phone: 99871-139-09-86, 152-16-54
>   Fax: 99871-152-16-50

As for how long it will be:

> Visas are issued within 7 calendar days from the day of presenting all documents

Comment: Excellent.  Am in Tajikistan now and may not go back through Toshkent anymore, but stranger things have happened.  Regardless, useful question and answer, so will accept.

Comment: @Mark Mayo By the link I've provided you can find the Kazakhstan Tajikistan-Embassy in Dushanbe, but you can ask another question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would propose a visit to the [Kazakhstan section of my website](https://caravanistan.com/visa/kazakhstan), which has more, better, and up-to-date information about obtaining a Kazakh visa than any other website.

See the embassy reports tab for info on the Tashkent embassy.

Comment: Thanks for the edit hippietrail! Don't want to come across as a spammer, but the top answer here is really very incomplete. I do tend to write tashkent with a capital but on a tablet everything is a hassle :-)

Answer (score -2):

The best place to check would be the ministry of foreign affairs of Kazakhstan, they have all the information you need.

Comment: I suspect this website might be in New York, USA yet here I am visiting it though I'm in Taiwan. Before websites there were things such as faxes, telephones, and letters. I suspect the Ministry might be contactable by one of those methods in addition to popping in in person. "check" ≠ "go there"

Comment: @ pnuts: Yes this is why one-liner answers are considered bad all across Stack Exchange. @AlexM do you have any such information to add? Here is [their website](http://www.mfa.kz/index.php/en/), here is [the "contact us" page](http://www.mfa.kz/index.php/en/contact-us), and here is [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ministry_of_Foreign_Affairs_(Kazakhstan)). I have not checked any of these for the answer.